# Suspicious software update

Tags: update-manager

Using 18.04 LTS. Update this morning shows a 10.2 Mb file to be downloaded but there are no details of the update nor any technical description. Seems suspicious to me, is it?

Comment: what does it say in terminal after `sudo apt upgrade`?